# Find invariant subspace of a shear - Maschke theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, invariant-subspace

Let's take the matrix $A$: \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}

This transformation on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a shear.
Note that $G = \langle A^n \mid n \in \mathbb{Z} \rangle$, is a subgroup of : $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$.
Moreover the subspace $E = \{\lambda \cdot {}^t (1 \quad0 ) \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is an invariant subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Yet by Maschke theorem, there exist a supplementary of $E$ that is an invariant subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, but when I am trying to visualize the transformation associated with $A$ I don't find this supplementary.

I feel like only the $x-$axis is invariant by a shear. That's why I think I am wrong somewhere. 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just proved that Maschke's theorem need not hold for infinite groups. Your $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, and Maschke's theorem does not hold for $\mathbb{Z}$. Have another look at the proof of Maschke to see where the finiteness of $G$ is used.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. Tought, it was true for infinite group.

Comment: It holds for _some_ infinite groups, but one needs some extra structure on the group to make it work. For example if $G$ is a compact Lie group, then you can recover almost the entire theory, including Maschke's theorem, by replacing the counting measure on a finite group by the Haar measure on your Lie group. But the representation theory of infinite discrete groups is hard!